# Java class exception not working as intended

Tags: java

I'm trying to simply make a class extend the class exception and i've seen multiple videos on it with the code setup the exact same way but I just have a different class name

```
public class CategoryException extends Exception {

   public CategoryException()
   {
   super("A category exception was thrown.");
   }//end method

   public CategoryException(String messagePassed)
   {
   super(messagePassed);
   }//end method



   }
```

All I want to do is pass this to my main code but this won't even compile and i'm very confused on why it it is saying that super has has no parameters but in the everything that i've seen this is how its supposed to be set up

```
CategoryException.java:5: error: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;
   super("A category exception was thrown.");
   ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
CategoryException.java:10: error: constructor Exception in class Exception cannot be applied to given types;
   super(messagePassed);
   ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
2 errors
```

thank you for any help as im very confused on what to do to get by this and I know i must be stupid or something to not realize it.

Comment: Is class `Exception` the usual `java.lang.Exception` or have you created your own `Exception` class? Your code compiles fine for me.

Comment: so I just imported the java.lang.exception for the class and that made it work but i don't get how from what i've seen other people do with their code they didn't need to do that to make it work. I apologize if i'm sounding dumb i might just be over thinking it. Thank you for helping me fix my code though.

Comment: If you have your own class named `Exception`, then that will be picked up instead of the standard class `java.lang.Exception`. Your class `CategoryException` then extends your own `Exception` class instead of the standard one, and that causes errors and confusion. Lesson: Don't give your own classes the same name as standard classes. Rename your own class `Exception` to something else.

Comment: You shouldn't import java.lang.Exception. All of java.lang is imported by default. You need to find where you've declared your own class Exception and get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do what you are looking for:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        try {
            throw new CategoryException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class CategoryException extends Exception {

    public CategoryException() {
        super("A category exception was thrown.");
    }

    public CategoryException(String messagePassed) {
        super(messagePassed);
    }
}
```

In this case so you can check that it works, the main method just catches your CategoryException and prints out the exception message "A category exception was thrown."